# Auto create slug field in django 1.5 models - example from django tutorial

Tags: django, django-models

I am quite new to Django and I am trying to auto create a slug field in django models. So, following the django 101 tutorial, I have tried to create the slug field from the following models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    slugp = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.question

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slugp = slugify(self.question)
        super(Poll, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then I use the django API as follows:

```
from writedb.models import Poll, Choice 
from django.utils import timezone
p = Poll(question="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
p.save
# out: <bound method Poll.save of <Poll: What's new?>>
p.slugp
#out: u''
```

Whatever I do the slugp field does not seem to get populated (or is the way I am accesing it wrong? I dont seem the field being populated in the database either) - I am wondering what I am doing wrong. Any pointers would be much appreciated - and sorry if this is a 101 question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo, but `p.save` needs to be `p.save()`. The former is just calling an attribute (as shown by the output `<bound method Poll.save of <Poll: What's new?>>`), while the latter is actually calling the save method

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony: I seemed to have been a complete idiot. It was indeed the missing () which was causing this. Please write it as an answer and I will accept this.

Comment: Just a tip: use ``slug`` instead of ``slugp``. Simplifies things a lot since that's the default name expected by many parts of Django, freeing you from having to explicitly specify the slug field in some cases.

Comment: @bvukelic: thanks for the tip. I will take that into account when developing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't calling the `save` method correctly. `p.save` needs to be `p.save()`. The former will just return the contents of the `save` attribute which is the method itself, where as the latter actually executes the method.